# what are essential requirements for writing kernel for microsoft windows

Tags: windows, linux, kernel

what should i learn as a programmer to write kernel like microsoft windows

i know c and c++ but what should i do to write kernel 
is it necessary to know basics of kernel programming of linux

how to become expert in both linux and windows kernel prograaming

Answer (score 5):

The guys at [OSR](http://www.osr.com/) have excellent seminars if you have the $. Otherwise, you can learn a lot from their website http://www.osr.com/.

UPDATE: they now have a site dedicated to self help here: http://www.osronline.com/.

Comment: =1 they were invaluable when I started.

Answer (score 2):

Following site may be useful to you

http://www.osdev.org/

Answer (score 1):

1. get yourself a [DDK or WDK](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/wdk/default.mspx)
2. read lots of documents or books. the WDK site has lots of resources.
3. wait, you want to be a kernel developer in MSFT? then you need a smart brain.

Comment: Everyone has to start somewhere you know - your point 3 is excessively dismissive

Answer (score 1):

You should probably start by getting experience working on other kernels like Linux.

Microsoft probably would not let you touch their kernel without experience.

If you mean driver development, then there are DDKs and tutorials all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

Learn about kernels. Learn to code kernel code. Writing device drivers is a start.

Answer (score 0):

[Learn C](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/CollegeAdvice.html) (and some other things).

Comment: Greg, that really isn't very helpful, but your answers usually are. Are you having a bad day?

Comment: Quite possibly, sorry about that. General malaise yesterday, but unlikely to be H1N1. Today is better!